# What is 思う doing in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, set-phrases

What does the first 思う, right after なったら, mean here?

> 私は大人になったら**思う**存分ライブに行きたいと思う。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the phrase [思う存分](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%80%9D%E3%81%86%E5%AD%98%E5%88%86), which means "to one's heart's content'.

The 思う refers the amount/share of something (分) that you *think* you want to do/have such that you are satisfied.

Alternatively, you could just leave it out and put a に before ライブ.

Comment: I didn't think 思う was part of 存分. Is 思う存分 more emphatic than just 存分?

Comment: I think so! :).